# No need HTTPS if i am going to use JOSE(JWT&JWE)?

Tags: https, jwt, jwe

I am recentlly finding a solution of Web Security, As far as i known the HTTPS will bring more security web, but i found another Security solution of JOSE(JWT&JWE) so i want to known, i use it in the future, can i just use HTTP only but without HTTPS ?

Kris.
Thanks

Comment: It depends on what do you actual need. Do you want to give privacy to users? Then yes, of course you have to use HTTPS.

Comment: Also confuse, the JWT&JWE could not give the privacy to the user ? As far  as i known , it will validate the data and encrypt the data, does it not enough for privacy to the user ?

Comment: There are a lot of concepts that you're skipping. What about sniffing the user history? Again, I don't know what are your actual needs. In any case, HTTPS will be more secure & private than anything under HTTP.

Comment: If i am going to use HTTPS , then no need  to use JOSE ?

Comment: HTTPS does guarantee the server identity, it prevents MITM. I have no idea how JWT are generated, didn't work with that yet but the previous reason is pretty convincing to do not use HTTP for any authentication process.

Comment: JOSE is designed by about two concepts one is Signing data, another is Encrypt the data. I suppose for signing a data is going to prevents the MITM ? As well known, JWT&JWE will be used for both authentication & authroization by OpenID Connect Protocol. I just confuse, if the HTTPS is enough, why JOSE&JWT&JWE ?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is legit to me and I am sorry to see that you received downvotes.

> As far as i known the HTTPS will bring more security web, but i found another Security solution of JOSE(JWT&JWE)

I think there is a confusion between the both technologies.

JWE is just a format that represents content using JSON based data structures and that provides integrity protection and encryption whereas HTTPS is a secured layer for the HTTP communication protocol.

**JWE is not a replacement to the HTTPS protocol**.
The use of one technology, the other one or both of them only depends on your application context. HTTPS may not be absolutely necessary in some contexts and the secured communication provided by other means.

You mentioned that you want to find a solution for a security application. A secured connection should be always used in that context.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely need HTTPS even if you are using JWTs and JWEs. HTTPS allows your client to verify that they are talking to the server they are expecting to talk to. It also protects the content of the communication, including the JWT/JWE tokens that you are using. Without HTTPS, anybody who can listen to the communication between your client and your server can impersonate your clients.

JWTs in particular can carry information about your user. You may not need to forward it to the authorization server that granted the token (if you are using an asymmetric signing key) and still have enough information about the identity and permissions of your user to grant or deny them access to the resources that you are protecting.